# Loop and Reorder Observable Array

Tags: knockout.js

I am using the following functions to sort an observableArray based on an integer value called sort:

```
model.sortColumns = function (a, b) {
  return a.Order > b.Order ? 1 : -1;
};

model.sortedColumns = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
  return this.reportFields.slice().sort(this.sortColumns);
}, model);
```

I am using a foreach to display them on screen and all works well, what I need to do now though is provide the ability in the foreach to change the order.  I was going to put simple up/down arrow icons with click events, but I'm not sure how to go about changing it, has anyone done anything like this before?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a great article about sorting and ordering: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/dragging-dropping-and-sorting-with.html

In this article all magic is done by using custom binding:

```
  ko.bindingHandlers.sortableList = {
      init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
          var list = valueAccessor();
          $(element).sortable({
              update: function(event, ui) {
                  //retrieve our actual data item
                  var item = ui.item.tmplItem().data;
                  //figure out its new position
                  var position = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(ui.item.parent().children(), ui.item[0]);
                  //remove the item and add it back in the right spot
                  if (position >= 0) {
                      list.remove(item);
                      list.splice(position, 0, item);
                  }
              }
          });
      }
  };

<div data-bind="foreach: sortedColumns, sortableList: sortedColumns"></div>
```

Comment: This caused all sorts of havoc, `$.ui.isOverAxis is not a function`