# switching input values via click binding

Tags: knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/z5935/6/

I need to add a `click` binding to each `button` that causes it's sibling `input` to switch values with the previous `input`.

Can anybody advise me of the best approach? Can I achieve this with a dependent observable or do I need a custom binding?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your goal is to change the order of the items. You can do this more easily with jQuery UI sortable and a custom binding, more info in this StackOverflow question:  [Loop and Reorder Observable Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230716/loop-and-reorder-observable-array)

Answer (score 0):

Sortable could be a good option for you depending on your situation.

If you want to persevere with KnockoutJS then I would suggest that you use the excellent array manipulation code in KO. So when you click on the move up or move down use the splice function here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html.

This allows you to remove and insert items at different indexes in the array. As it's an observable array the UI will redraw automagically.

HTH